# Prime-NG P-CHIPS Numbers only for Array of Numbers

Tags: angular, primeng

How can I enforce user to enter only numbers using `p-chips` component?

I want to fill array of `numbers` from user input.

Is there any alternative way to achieve this other than `p-chips` component?

Answer (score 7):

By using `p-chips` component, you can use `onAdd` method to check user input :

**HTML**

```
<p-chips [(ngModel)]="values" (onAdd)=checkInput($event)></p-chips>
```

**TS**

```
  checkInput(event) {
    this.errorMessage = ''; // reinitialize error message

    if(!this.isInt(event.value)) {
      this.errorMessage = event.value + ' is not an integer !'; // display error message
      this.values.pop(); // remove last entry from values
    }
  }
```

See [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/CojCsvLoQNgDFhoEZb1K?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

Or you can access the input element of the chips component like this and change input type to number;

`<p-chips #chips></p-chips>`

```
@ViewChild('chips', { static: true}) chips: Chips;

ngAfterViewInit() {
    (this.chips.inputViewChild.nativeElement as HTMLInputElement).type = "number";
}
```