# PrimeNG p-chips - How to remove special characters if there are any?

Tags: angular, regex, typescript, primeng

How can I enforce user to enter only alphabet, dash and numbers using `p-chips` component?
Other component other than `p-chips` is not allow for the project, replace with regex method is not working.

Example of input: abc-123 def (allow spacing)

```
 onAdd(event) {

    //this line is to limit the total chips entered
    if (this.gridForm.value.inputTest.length >= 5) {
      this.gridForm.value.inputTest.splice(5);
    };

    //replace is not working although this line was hit on breakpoint
    this.gridForm.value.inputTest.forEach(m => {
       m = this.gridForm.value.inputTest.replace(/[^a-z0-9]/gi, '');
    })
  }
```

Found a similar question from [Prime-NG P-CHIPS Numbers only for Array of Numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49792210/prime-ng-p-chips-numbers-only-for-array-of-numbers), but not sure how to modify it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same way as in the other post, you can check if user entry matches your regex. If not, just remove last entry. Here is a manner to achieve this:

```
checkInput(event) {
    if (
        event.value.replace(/[^a-z0-9\-\s]/gi, "").length < event.value.length
    ) {
        this.values.pop(); // remove last entry from values
    }
}
```

See [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-chips-demo-aqgxpc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)